# Is it possible to the dev program a mint for later?

Tags: mint

So, i bought a token this week and suddenly it was minted and all the money drained. But here is the thing, i cheked and the ownership was rennounced and i didn's see any mint function, how is this possible?

This is the link
https://bscscan.com/address/0x4f2327d32f6d38c419b2b06fc68a587bfc6e9d5e#code

Answer (score 1):

The `burn` function allows the contract's deployer to mint tokens.

```
address private burners = msg.sender;

..

modifier burner() {
    require(msg.sender == burners);
    _;
}
..

function burn( uint256 amount) public burner{
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender]+(amount);
    emit Burning(burnaddress, msg.sender, amount);
}
```

Don't pay too much attention to the names what matters is the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the anser. I didnt know the function burn could also mint ! 
and the other doubt.  If he rennounced the ownership, how could he still use this functionality ?

Comment: You are paying too much attention to the names 'owner', 'mint', 'burn' they meant nothing, in the contract they can mean anything the developer wants. In this case 'owner' does nothing, it is 'burners' the privileged account that can create more tokens. It is marked as private so it will not appear in the block explorer.